# The Maggid of Mezeritch on jewels and straw

Tags: sources-mekorot, chasidut-hasidism, quotations

In [his sermon on the ethics of controversy](https://archives.yu.edu/gsdl/collect/lammserm/index/assoc/HASH1161.dir/doc.pdf), R Norman Lamm says:

> The great Maggid of Mezeritch, the leading theoretician of Hasidism
> and one who knew only too well the life of controversy, told us never
> to be discouraged when we face violent opposition.  Sometimes we
> should accept it as a compliment:  the highway robber attacks the man
> who bears jewels, he never bothers with a man who drives a wagon of
> straw or refuse.

Can anyone help me find the source of this quote?

Comment: Don't know that quote or source but imo the following may be helpful to you or related - namely that the Klal is "A war to H' on Amalek" etc. and "Head of the nations is Amalek" - who attacks to conceal specifically the Rosh Bayit the True Tzaddik lest Yisrael be mitkarev to him and be redeemed. This is discussed in https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Translation:Likutei_Halakhot/Orach_Chayim#Halakhah_5 etc and in many other Sifrei Breslev and Nanach